# Compton Scattering- Photon Energy

Tags: photons, x-rays

In the compton scattering, if we were to relate the energy of the incident photon with the energy of the scattered photon, it is right to say; 
Incident photon energy = scattered photon energy + work function of the target atom + kinetic energy of the recoiled electron

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) It would be nice if you put your equations into well-readable formulas - you might want to visit the help section for that.

Comment: The relationship I have wrote is very clear and understandable. Could you please answer the question?

Comment: Compton scattering is considered to be perfectly elastic. There is no work function in a first order analysis. See the hyperphysics link: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/compeq.html#c1

Comment: @BillN So how is possible for us to say that the the electron is freed from the atom, if no mention of its bounding energy is mentioned in the analysis?

Comment: @Lilly being rude is the best way to not be answered. Have a fun time here.

Answer (score 2):

The X-ray photons photons of energy ~ MeV collide with electrons which are bound to the nuclei of atoms.
As the binding energy of these electrons (~eV) is much smaller than the energy of the incoming photons the electrons are treated as though they are stationary and free and so this binding energy is neglected.

The work function energy is all to do with the energy needed by an electron to escape from a material.